# Is a multiple-wavelengths antenna possible in UHF and up?

Tags: antenna, uhf, antenna-theory

I know that in the High Frequency regions of the ham bands, the antennas have to be sub-wavelength because most people just can't put up a 160 meter full-size antenna.

Let's say we're in the 23 centimeter or an even higher band. Can the antenna lengths there be, let's say, twice, four times, etc., as large?

Comment: Well, *length*, I doubt it. *Size*, yes, absolutely. A high-gain antenna is much more practical at 23 cm than at 20 meters simply because the physical dimensions are smaller. Stacked dipoles can provide you with vertical gain and horizontal omnidirectionality; this is reasonably practical on two meters, and very practical on 70 cm and up.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling precisely what orientation and stacking do you have in mind for that statement?

Comment: @PhilFrost Something like e.g. [this one](http://www.svebry.se/gp-9n-vertikalantenn-i-glasfiber-144-430-mhz/3662-0) (a 5.1 meters long vertical antenna giving you a specified 8.5 dBi on 144 MHz and 11.9 dBi on 432 MHz; the web page is in Swedish, but the data should be understandable enough and there is a picture for illustration). I've seen plenty of similar constructions.

Comment: @Optionparty How does "Discone antenna" answer the question "is a multiple-wavelengths antenna possible"?

Comment: @Optionparty I believe you are reading the question wrong. It's not "multiple wavelengths" as in "works equally well on a number of different frequencies", but rather "multiple wavelengths" as in "the physical size of the antenna is several wavelengths at the operating frequency". This interpretation is supported by the accepted answer being what it is. Is that the reason for your original comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People can, and do, put up full size 160m antennas. Usually "full size" means a 1/2 wavelength dipole, or a 1/4 wave vertical. The vertical works because the 1/4 element is "mirrored" by the ground plane, creating an image antenna, which makes it very much like a 1/2 wave dipole.

1/2 wavelength seems like a magic number because it is the minimum length required to attain resonance. Antennas can be made smaller and resonated by introducing additional, non-radiating reactive components like inductors or capacitors. However, shortening the antenna in this way makes the antenna less efficient.

Making the antenna *longer* than 1/2 wavelength isn't frequently done because in most cases there isn't much point to it. As the antenna first becomes longer than 1/2 wavelength, it stops being resonant. If made longer to 1.5 wavelengths, it becomes resonant again. However, it isn't any more efficient than a 1/2 wavelength antenna. In fact, it's likely *less* efficient, because the current must now travel over more antenna, which has more resistance.

What making the antenna longer does do is alter the radiation pattern. For example, compare a 1/2 wave dipole (in free space):

[image: 1/2 wave dipole radiation pattern]

to a 1.5 wave dipole:

[image: 1.5 wave dipole radiation pattern]

These are from [antenna-theory.com](http://www.antenna-theory.com/antennas/dipole.php).

Is this really useful? Usually no. One possible exception might be for verticals, where making the antenna longer (to a point, usually 5/8 wavelength) lowers the takeoff angle a bit.

Comment: Not to add another answer to an old question, but I don't see **longwire antennas** (not beverage, multi-lambda length of wire, terminated in a resistor to ground) mentioned anywhere in this discussion. For the mentioned 23cm band, a "minimum" 4-wave longwire would be just under a meter long, and with 5-10 meters of wire one could get some really impressive gain/directionality without having to "snip and check" to tune for resonance!

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB Do longwire antennas differ significantly from long dipoles? I think in the end the effect is much the same: you get increasingly more lobes in the pattern but it doesn't "pick up more signal" (and you need an antenna tuner).

Comment: It differs from a long dipole in 3 ways: 1-It's end-fed, more like a 1/4 wave "whip" than a dipole; 2-It's _unidirectional_, being fed from one end and terminated resistively to ground at the other gives a front-back ratio >1:1 and also makes it non resonant; 3-It's non-resonant. The non-fed end is terminated resistively to ground, so no resonating open end & no requirement for a matching network/antenna tuner (though an impedance-matching balun/unun might be called for if your termination resistor doesn't equal xmitter impedance or you use a balanced transmission line)

Comment: I'm confused. Earlier you said "not beverage", but now what you are describing sounds like a Beverage antenna.

Comment: I may be wrong, but by my understanding a "beverage" antenna is open at the non-fed end, like a large version of the "random wire" antenna.

Comment: @ KV5ROB- I did a long wire antenna for receive on UHF TV (ch 57 analog) years ago before I became a ham....directional is putting it politely. So directional that a gust of wind would make it go from full signal to just raster. If Memory serves it was roughly 15/4 wave long.

Comment: @resident_heretic Exactly.  People have used homebrew UHF rhombic antennas in their attic. They are multiple-wavelength antennas, and I'm told that they worked well.

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB A [Beverage antenna](http://www.w0btu.com/Beverage_antennas.html) can either be terminated or unterminated. Terminating the far end improves the F/B ratio; unterminated, the F/B is about 10 dB.

Comment: @MikeWaters Thanks for that info. I was using the antenna names/descriptions from my PAH book for both "longwire" and "beverage" antennae. If the bev. is mentioned as beingg optionally terminated in there, I missed it (which is possible, since the bev. never piqued my personal interest much). The "longwire" is, however, described as >= 4 waves in length & requires resistive termination.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could create, instead of a 1/2 wave dipole, a full wave dipole. They get very directional after you pass full-wave in length as shown in graphs at http://www.antenna-theory.com/antennas/dipole.php.

However, most folks instead use a collinear dipole array of multiple dipoles stacked, or side-by-side, or both, for gain.

Answer (score 0):

You may be asking about what is known as a “[log-periodic antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-periodic_antenna).”

Comment: Could you say more about how a log-periodic antenna is relevant? As the article says, a LPDA consists of a number of _half-wave_ dipole elements, not longer ones. Is there a type of log-periodic antenna that has elements larger than 1/2 wavelength?